# When I click a link on my S8 Chrome browser the link opens elsewhere?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

How do I make my S8 Chrome browser open links clicked within it, to open in it & not the Samsung browser?

Comment: It is possible the Samsung Browser has control as the default browser. Investigate Settings> Apps> Settings (the cog)> Default Apps, and set your choice as the browser app default. The exact path text may vary slightly by OS version, but will generally get you to the same functionality.

Comment: If  above suggestions didn't help, try [Chromer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arun.com.chromer) browser, which is practically Chrome and can be configured to open links in it, when you click a link on Chrome. I use it a lot and am happy with it

Answer (score 0):

Your Samsung browser must have become the default browser for certain links. And therefore it always redirects you to that browser.

To stop that from happening go into your phone settings -> apps -> Samsung browser -> set as default -> clear defaults.

Now, the next time you press on a similar link, it will ask you which app you want to open it in, select the chrome browser as the default.

Sometimes chrome will force you to open links in an external app, for example YouTube will always open in it's app. To avoid that, you can open the link as a new tab, by long pressing on the link and selecting "open in New tab"